# Inductor made from a microwave transformer is LOUD (as in high decibel)...any tricks to tone it down?

Tags: inductor

I built a choke coil out of a MOT which was recommended in another post to reduce ripple voltage in my electric kiln project and was surprised by how LOUD it was. I have placed it on a piece of plywood with a rubber material between the coil and the wood to help reduce vibration. It's better than when I had it mounted on the metal wall, but it gets super loud at higher voltages. Anyone have a nice trick for minimizing the noise created by this type of device?

I was hoping to get a 2.0mH inductor from this project but an LCR meter showed 1.6mH. I wound it until I ran out of space with 10 AWG. Probably 30 turns. Would more turns with 12 AWG give a higher inductance?

I looked at the waveform and it was much less smooth than I had hoped. The "jagged teeth" seen with the bridge alone become more rounded but far from a smooth looking DC signal. Not really worth the horrible noise. I would include an image of the waveform but my scope shorted out when I set it down. Tough day.

Update with photos:
Here are my pictures of the components and a schematic. It's been taken off the kiln as I continue to troubleshoot. The bridge remains in place as its install has been seamless. Thanks for reviewing!

[image: Choke]

[image: Components]

[image: Schematic]

Comment: @DanielVanAntwerp - Hi, (a) This is now your 4th question on the same project. You haven't accepted an answer on any of the previous ones, which implies to readers of those that you still want answers. BUT at least one of them seems to be obsolete, as you have *moved* from the question with [this answer](/a/628850), to asking *this* question above about making an inductor. At this point, the situation is getting more tangled with each new overlapping question (and each long stream of comments that it generates).

Comment: (b) If any of the previous questions are now obsolete, how will you prevent future readers wasting time trying to answer a now-obsolete question? Perhaps review each question and [accept](/help/someone-answers) the best answer you got to *that* question (even if it wasn't the total solution to your overall problem)? Or, if you don't want to accept an answer, at the very least, leave a bold warning in the question saying it is now obsolete. We may then close the question for you.

Comment: (c) As a minimum, you should add a link in each question, to every other question where you ask about the same project. Otherwise someone reading 1 question is only getting part of the overall picture. That is one of the problems with this being a "whole project"-type of situation and, although site members are very helpful, these are sometimes known as "chameleon questions" as they keep changing and are not a good fit for Stack Exchange's (deliberately) rigid Q&A format, where the question is expected to be well-formed, complete, and quite importantly, not change (outside of clarifications).

Comment: (d) The number of comments has exceeded what is reasonable (with no sign of finishing). Therefore it has been moved to chat and should be continued there (link below). -- As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, any further comments posted here might be deleted without notice. **Keep it in chat now, please!** When someone has got enough information from the chat to post an answer, then please do that as usual. Any updates to the question which are decided during the chat, should be made via an edit to the question, not as a comment. Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138615/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-van-antwerp-inductor-made-from-a-microwave-tran).